# Thread task not exiting when atomic value changed

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

The problem I am facing is that the application does not exit when I type "exit" in the console. It gets stuck in the follwing thread:

```
void server<T>::handleClientConnections(int serverSocketFD, std::atomic<bool> &__flag)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> __threads;

    while (__flag.load())
    {
        acceptedSocket newAcceptedSocket;

        if (!acceptConnection(serverSocketFD, newAcceptedSocket))
            continue;

        connectedSockets.push_back(newAcceptedSocket);

        std::thread thread(&server::receivedDataHandlerThread, this, newAcceptedSocket);
        thread.detach();

        __threads.push_back(std::move(thread));
    }

    for (auto &thread : __threads)
        thread.join();

    for (const auto &socket : connectedSockets)
        close(socket.getAcceptedSocketFD());
}
```

I am creating a thread for each connection and I am using an atomic variable to signal the other threads. (SERVER_RUNNING is declared as a global std::atomic)

```
template <typename T>
void server<T>::consoleListener(std::atomic<bool> &__flag)
{
    underline(75);

    char input[101] = "";

    while (__flag.load())
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << " "
                  << "--> ";
        std::cin >> input;

        if (strcasecmp(input, "exit") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << " "
                      << "Shutting down...\n";

            __flag.store(false);

            break;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void server<T>::server_easy_init(int serverSocketFD)
{
    SERVER_RUNNING.store(true);

    std::thread workerThread(&server::handleClientConnections, this, serverSocketFD, std::ref(SERVER_RUNNING));

    consoleListener(std::ref(SERVER_RUNNING));

    workerThread.join();
}
```

Thank you!

I tried using a mutex and the condition variable, but I encountered the same bug.

Comment: If you `detach()` a thread, it's no longer `joinable()`. Detaching is very, very rarely needed.

Comment: OT: Please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) TL;DR: All symbols beginning with double underscore are *reserved*, and you should not define symbols with such names yourself.

Comment: Recommendation: back up the code and then hack it down to an [mre] (MRE). Normally you'll find the problem without our help part way through making the MRE, but threading... That stuff gets tricky. And it makes the MRE all the more important because we can run it and see where things went sideways, test solutions, and write answers that descend directly from the question, helping future askers understand the problem and the solution.

Comment: Side note: names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__threads`, `__flag`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: OT: If you are using C++17 or older `std::cin >> input;` is very dangerous since that could write out of bounds. Use `std::cin >> std::setw(sizeof input) >> input;` or better, use a `std::string` .

Comment: Btw, since you're detach()ing the threads, keeping the instances is kind of pointless. I'm surprised the join() works, but I guess it's just a no-op instead of throwing an error -- too lazy to look it up

Comment: I'm guessing your `acceptConnection` is sitting there in a `listen`-call -- changing your atomic is not an interrupt. I don't know what the rest of your code does, but since you're accepting connections, other threads might be sitting in their `read` calls... there's a reason why I generally recommend the use of libraries to do networking in C++.

Comment: @ChristianStieber No, [`join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) isn't noop here, it would throw `std::system_error`. Presumably the code never leaves the first loop, so it doesn't get to `join()` calls.

Comment: It doesnt leave the loop. The acceptConnection function just uses the accept sys call, extracts relevant information about the connection (like client address) and stores it in the acceptedSocket

Comment: I can not really figure out how to cleanup the threads. The app works if I leave it running. I do not know how to shut it down correctly.

Comment: Oh... yeah, I guess the thing not leaving the loop makes it not hit the join() -- my bad. Same about the listen call -- that's accept(). Still, it's probably blocked in there, so you'd have to make another connection before it sees the change to the atomic variable....

Comment: @SorinTudose that's because you really can't. If you have blocking calls, they'll block. Since you're using Unix calls you could try to work with signals, but in my book, these always fall into the "big mess" category. It's somewhat easier with non-blocking I/O since you're only stuck in select/poll calls -- in order to avoid signals, I generally use a pipe to wake them up. But, in summary, instead of learning these things, I would learn a library instead -- you are basically doing very low level stuff here.

Comment: As a side note, depending on what you're doing, you might not have to clean up the threads at all: it seems you're doing this before you exit the program anyway -- but, exiting a program will kill threads and free memory...

Comment: The question seems to imply (although the code doesn't show it) that the type of `__flag` is `std::atomic<bool>`. If so, there's no need to call `__flag.load()` or `_flag.store()`. `while (__flag)` will implicitly do the load, and `__flag = false;` will do the appropriate store. Also, `flag` is a terrible name. Of course that's a flag; that's why the code keeps checking it. What does the flag **mean**? Give it a name that describes its role: `done`, `keep_running`, whatever.

Comment: Ok, I renamed it.

Comment: @Christian Stieber So in conclusion is there a way to kill the loop in handleClientConnections function? Because it seems that it does not end despite the atomic var?

Comment: @SorinTudose the important question is whether it's really stuck in the `accept()` call, like I'm suspecting. This basically means it's sitting there waiting for a new connection, and it's not going to check your atomic until it gets a new connection and exits the call. If that's the case, then the options are "no, there is no way", using Unix signals which is messy to say the least, or... make a connection to the socket yourself to make the accept call return. Or rewrite the entire thing to use non-blocking I/O, in which case you'll have fewer threads as well. Or a mix... next conmment :-)

Comment: You could also do something weird: since accept() doesn't have a timeout parameter, you could treat it as a non-blocking socket anyway, select() on it, and use a timeout on that :-) The problem with that is you're effectively doing a polling., which is a BIG no-no in any kind of modern programming where it's not absolutely required.

Comment: Something like this? 

fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(serverSocketFD, &readfds);
        
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int activity = select(serverSocketFD + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

And than check the activity value?

Comment: Nvm, it works wow.  The program stopped. Thanks dude!

Answer (score -1):

This is what the updated code:

```
template <typename T>
void server<T>::receivedDataHandlerThread(const class acceptedSocket __socket)
{
    std::thread(&server::receivedDataHandler, this, __socket).detach();
}

template <typename T>
void server<T>::handleClientConnections(int serverSocketFD, std::atomic<bool> &__flag)
{
    while (__flag)
    {
         // Set up the file descriptor set for select
        fd_set readfds;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(serverSocketFD, &readfds);
        
        // Set timeout
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 1; // 1 second timeout
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        // Wait for activity on server socket
        int activity = select(serverSocketFD + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        if (activity == -1)
        {
            perror("select");
            break;
        }
        else if (activity == 0)
            continue;
        else
        {
            acceptedSocket newAcceptedSocket;

            if (!acceptConnection(serverSocketFD, newAcceptedSocket))
                continue;

            connectedSockets.push_back(newAcceptedSocket);

            receivedDataHandlerThread(newAcceptedSocket);
        }
    };

    for (const auto &socket : connectedSockets)
        close(socket.getAcceptedSocketFD());
}
```

But now I get a couple memory leaks :)

```
==110270== HEAP SUMMARY:
==110270==     in use at exit: 1,724 bytes in 8 blocks
==110270==   total heap usage: 13,999 allocs, 13,991 frees, 2,431,800 bytes allocated
==110270== 
==110270== 912 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 4
==110270==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==110270==    by 0x40147D9: calloc (rtld-malloc.h:44)
==110270==    by 0x40147D9: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:375)
==110270==    by 0x40147D9: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:634)
==110270==    by 0x4C157B4: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:430)
==110270==    by 0x4C157B4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.34 (pthread_create.c:647)
==110270==    by 0x4A10328: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30)
==110270==    by 0x116129: std::thread::thread<void (net::server<char>::*)(net::server<char>::acceptedSocket), net::server<char>*, net::server<char>::acceptedSocket const&, void>(void (net::server<char>::*&&)(net::server<char>::acceptedSocket), net::server<char>*&&, net::server<char>::acceptedSocket const&) (std_thread.h:143)
==110270==    by 0x111A78: net::server<char>::receivedDataHandlerThread(net::server<char>::acceptedSocket) (serverUtils.cpp:528)
==110270==    by 0x111958: net::server<char>::handleClientConnections(int, std::atomic<bool>&) (serverUtils.cpp:565)
==110270==    by 0x11908E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > >(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (net::server<char>::*&&)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*&&, int&&, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> >&&) (invoke.h:74)
==110270==    by 0x118D9A: std::__invoke_result<void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > >::type std::__invoke<void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > >(void (net::server<char>::*&&)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*&&, int&&, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> >&&) (invoke.h:96)
==110270==    by 0x118B2A: void std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > > >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul, 2ul, 3ul>) (std_thread.h:259)
==110270==    by 0x118A19: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > > >::operator()() (std_thread.h:266)
==110270==    by 0x1189B5: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (net::server<char>::*)(int, std::atomic<bool>&), net::server<char>*, int, std::reference_wrapper<std::atomic<bool> > > > >::_M_run() (std_thread.h:211)
==110270== 
==110270== LEAK SUMMARY:
==110270==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==110270==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==110270==      possibly lost: 912 bytes in 3 blocks
==110270==    still reachable: 812 bytes in 5 blocks
==110270==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==110270== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==110270== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==110270== 
==110270== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==110270== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Anyways, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).